# How is 役に立った ( helpful ) formed?

Tags: grammar, words, syntax, expressions, particle-に

My guess is that the phrase is derived from the composition of the following:

1. 役 (yaku) : service, use
2. に：particle for destination
3. 立った：perfective of 立つ (tatsu)

So it's extended meaning like "rise to a supporting role", "being supported".

Am I more or less correct?

===

I have read posts:

[Is "役立つ" a recent lexicalization of "役に立つ"? Is it less formal?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36268)

[Difference Between 手伝う, 力になる, and 役に立つ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/87629)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

役に立つ is a fixed phrase that has to be learned by rote, but if I really have to analyze it...

- **役**: "service", "use"
- **に**: Here, it's a role marker rather than a destination marker. In other words, it's more like "as X" or "for X" rather than "to X". See: [Can に have the same function as として?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/82913/5010)
- **立つ**: This is a [light verb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/42912/8629) that has [dozens of possible translations](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A4) including "to form", "to work/serve (as)", "to excel (at)", "to be viable", "to be realized", "to be made" and so on.

So a super-literal translation of 役に立った would be "served for (some) use" or "was viable as service".

Similar set phrases where 立つ is used in a similar manner include:

- 予定が立つ
- 腕が立つ
- 申し訳が立つ
- 面目が立つ

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct. But I think that in this context the meaning of 立つ is "to stand still" rather than "to rise".

に doesn't function as a particle of destination but as an adverbializer (look the last entry [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%AB). It modifies the verb, it tells us how the verb is performed.

So in a sentence like:

> それは役に立つ。

それ is the subject who stands up (立つ) in a way that is helpful (役に).

You may have other aditional に particles indicating time, location, etc.

Have in mind that the subject is not always what marked by は. For example:

> 俺にしてはとても役に立つ。

Meaning: As for me, (it) is really helpful.

The subject is always marked by が, but when it is not present you'll have to deduce it from context.